# Navbar dentro de uma imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Olá, estou fazendo um navbar e queria que todos os botões ficassem dentro de uma imagem dessa forma: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Rodei em um monte de site mas nenhum falava especificamente sobre esse tópico, então se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Meu código:

```css
@keyframes pular{
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0)
    }
    40%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px)
    }
    80%{
        -webkit-transfomr: translateY(-10px);
        transform: translateY(-10px)
    }
}

.pulo:hover{
    animation: pular 1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pokemon Generations</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="Logo/Dream_Poké_Ball_Sprite.png">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Daniel Lucas">
        <meta name="description" content="Tela Inicial do site">
        <meta name="keywords" content="pokémon,bingo,história">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <body style="background-image: url(Fundo/fundo_pokemon_branco.jpg)">
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color:#38102b" > 
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0" href="site_inicial.htm"><img src="Logo/shining_legends.png"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSite" > 
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="icone_personagens_gold.png" >Personagens</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="icone_comojogar_gold.png" >Como jogar</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="icone_jogar_gold1.png" >Jogar</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="icone_atualizacoes_gold.png" >Atualizações</button></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-5"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" class="ml-1"><img src="icone_quemsou_gold.png" >Quem Sou</button></a></li>

                        <li class="nav-item " id="charmander"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo" target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6VdsMMnL-GdcoKc9qZEtQA?disable_polymer=true"><img src="Icones/icone_charmander.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo " target="_blank" href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=5584996011922"><img src="Icones/icone_bulbasaur.png"></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-brand h1 mb-0 pulo" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/LegendsShining"><img src="Icones/icone_squirtle.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </nav>


    </body>
</html>
```

O CÓDIGO ACIMA ESTÁ SEM AS IMAGENS
A imagem que será o navbar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc que fazer essa barra customizando uma NavBar nativa do Bootstrap? Ou um exemplos simples sem usar o Bootstrap te ajuda? To te perguntando isso pq a NavBar do Bootstrap já vem por default com UM MONTE de CSS original do próprio Bootstrap e esses CSS mais vão atrapalhar do que ajudar a fazer uma Nav tão customizada quanto o que vc quer...  O ideal é vc fazer o seu menu e não usar a Nav original do Bootstrap...

Comment: Eu tô usando o bootstrap mais pelo redimensionamento do que qualquer outra coisa, aí teria como fazer esse menu com algumas classes do bootstrap tipo a navbar-expand-lg?

Comment: Só desenhar a Navbar não é tão complicado, mas fazer ela ficar responsiva que seria mais chato... Vc tem que pensar como vai tratar esse menu em telas pequenas. Mas a minha dica é vc fazer uma barra nova e não usar a NavBar original do Bootstrap pq ela já vem com um monte de CSS que o Bootstrap coloca nela que mais vai atrapalhar do que ajudar! Se vc quiser um exemplo sem usar a Nav do bootstrap posso te dar uma ajuda, mas pra customizar e transforma a Nav do BS nessa Nav, acho que nem vale a pena...

Comment: Pode ser sem a nav do bootstrap então, depois eu me viro pra fazer o redimensionamento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estamos aqui para ensinar a pescar e não para entregar o peixe. Então só fiz o lado esquerdo do menu, o lado direito vc faz ;)

Repare que ficou bem flexível, usei `flex`, e dependendo do tamanho do texto do link vai funcionar bem na maioria das telas...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Primeiro, obviamente eu usei a forma que eu achei mais prática, mas talvez tenha outras melhores***

Para o link da ponta esquerda eu usei `transform skewX` para inclinar nos dos lados do link, e no segundo item da esquerda eu usem um `linear-gradiente` em `45deg`, assim a inclinação fica só em um lado e o outro fica reto. Já para Navbar vermelha no fundo para fazer o angula nos cantos eu usei dois *pseudo-elementos*, um em cada canto, e cada um deles com um `linear-gradiente` tb em `45deg` com a mesma cor do fundo, branco... Se quiser pode usar sua imagem como `background-imagem` que não vai mudar muito, depois é só remover os *pseudo-elementos* do CSS se optar por isso.

O seu dever de casa é fazer agora o lado da direita. Repare que eu não usei nada do Bootstrap, mesmo assim, deixei ele indexado na página, para vc ver que não tem conflito entro o que eu fiz e as classes do BS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>

.menu {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  color: darkred;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.menu::after,
.menu::before {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.menu::after {
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, transparent 51%);
}
.menu::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, transparent 51%);
  right: 0;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(40px);
  width: calc(25% - 40px);
}
.item:nth-child(1) a{
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, darkred 0, darkred 45px, gold 41px);
}
.item:nth-child(2) a{
  transform: translateX(calc(45px / 2));
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ahhh, obrigado cara, me salvou

Comment: @Akali que bom que ajudou, ai no exemplo tem varias técnicas aplicadas, então tem coisas ai que podem te ajudar no futuro em outros layouts. Abs